# How to change header title dynamically

Tags: react-native

I built a React Native app which has 2 tabs for change screen. When I change a screen I would like to change also the title of the header. So when I press Tab 1 the tile is Tab 1 and Tab 2 if Tab 2 screen is on. 
I would like to understand what kind of change or add I need to do to perform that action in my code. Iùm sharing the code where I think should be done the change but if Iùm wrong please guide me to the right code I should share. I'm new to Native and I'm trying to learn it.

I have a Route.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Platform, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import FlightsTabNavigator from "./App/navigations/FlightsTabNavigator";
import FlightsHeader from "./App/components/header/FlightsHeader";
import HeaderStyle from "./App/styles/HeaderStyle";
import s from "./App/styles/headerImgStyle";

const Routes = createStackNavigator({
    FlightsTabNavigator: {
        screen: FlightsTabNavigator,

    }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'FlightsTabNavigator',
    navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: '',
        headerBackground: (
            <Image
                style={s.image}
                //source={require('./App/assets/header/header.jpg')}
                source={{uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503365113766-4a362681eac5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=79cf794378a008ab1d74b8e612d72ad0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80'}}
            />
        ),
        header: props => <FlightsHeader {...props} />,
        ...HeaderStyle,
        animationEnabled: true
    }

});

export default Routes;
```

And the Header:

```
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "react-navigation";
import { View, Text, Platform, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const FlightsHeader = props => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Header {...props} />
        </View>
    );
};

export default FlightsHeader;
```

Comment: You can check their docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html. Maybe `navigationOptions` is the answer

Comment: @anhtu I tried to use the doc but cannot understand in my code how to use it. Need help to understand where to put that kind of info.

Comment: Put 'navigationOptions' in each route/screen/component